# Adding A Face / Faces between two objects

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, faces

I have a Hemisphere inside another hemisphere as per the picture below:[image: Hemisphere with child]

I am extremely new to blender, but would like to create a face between the outer and inner hemispheres. I have selected all the vertices around the "cut" on both the inner and outer object and then used "create face" and was hoping to end up with essentially a solid object with a "scoop" taken out of it - kind of like if someone scooped the yoke out of a hard-boiled egg. Instead, a face was created across the entire surface - so that the inner hemisphere was completely hidden. I was also hoping this would work because each shape has the same number of vertices around the edges I wish to join (the smaller hemisphere was simply copied and rescaled from the larger one).

How might I achieve this goal of ending up with a single solid-looking object? Many thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single face cannot have "holes" in it. You can create two faces instead. For example

[image]

Comment: Perfect - thank you for helping me take my initial steps with this. I've learned a general rule that's bound to become part of what I do in the future!